# "What have we here?" vs. "What do we have here?"

Tags: subject-verb-inversion, questions, emphasis

Could someone explain which structure is correct and if it's okay to say the other one?

> Oh, what have we here?
>
> Oh, what do we have here?

Can we simply invert the subject and the verb to make a sentence interrogative as in French?

Comment: Both are acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither is incorrect. The second is the more direct and obvious way to phrase the question. The first conjures perhaps a slight sense of antiquity or formality, because you would not expect to hear it in casual speech; it also has common literary use.